# VBA Excel Combining Rows Based on Matching Column Cells, appending non matching data to new columns

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, append

I've searched around to try and find an existing solution to this but I could only find variations where people wanted their duplicated data concatenated into a single cell, I'm trying to combine rows with duplicated values in column C and append the column J data into a single row across a few new columns. Example here;

```
   Column A     Column C       Column J
        1       Company A      Contact 1
        2       Company A      Contact 2
        3       Company B      Contact 1
        4       Company B      Contact 2
        5       Company B      Contact 3
```

And I need to convert it to this:

```
Column A    Column C     Column S     Column AC     Column AM
    1       Company A    Contact 1    Contact 2
    2       Company B    Contact 1    Contact 2     Contact 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to take such an example you speak of and adapt it to your needs?

Comment: Are the duplicate rows next to each other?

Comment: Yes Thomas we will have it ordered on column C AtoZ so they would be next to each other.

Comment: Are there more than 3 contacts?

Comment: There could be up to 10 contacts in rare cases tjb, which I'd like moved into columns every 10 columns apart, so starting at S for contact1, AC, AM, AW, BG, BQ, CA, CK,CU,DE. Hope this helps.

Comment: Are there are blank cells in the columns?

Comment: No contact cells will be blank Thomas but some other columns could sometimes be blank.

Comment: How many cells do you want to move up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. data is in `Sheet1`
2. result will be displayed in `Sheet2`
3. `Sheet1`has header in `Row 1` and data starts from `Row 2`

---

```
Sub Demo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim dict1 As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, count As Long, rowCntr As Long, lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim inputWS As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet
    Dim arr() As Variant

    'set your sheets here
    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set inputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    'defining columns in array
    arr = Array("S", "AC", "AM", "AW", "BG", "BQ", "CA", "CK", "CU", "DE")

    'get last row with data in Sheet1
    lastRow = inputWS.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'put unique compny names in dictionary
    c1 = inputWS.Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
    For i = 1 To UBound(c1, 1)
        dict1(c1(i, 1)) = 1
        Debug.Print c1(i, 1)
    Next i

    rowCntr = 1
    For Each k In dict1.keys
        Debug.Print k, dict1(k)
        'find first occurrence of company name in Column C
        Set rFound = inputWS.Columns(3).Find(What:=k)
        strRow = rFound.Row
        strCol = rFound.Column
        outputWS.Range("A" & rowCntr) = dict1(k)
        outputWS.Range("C" & rowCntr) = rFound
        'get count of each company in column C
        count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(inputWS.Range("C1:C" & lastRow), rFound)
        For i = 1 To count
            'get all the contact numbers
            outputWS.Range(arr(i - 1) & rowCntr) = inputWS.Range("J" & strRow)
            strRow = strRow + 1
        Next i
        rowCntr = rowCntr + 1
    Next k

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: This was the code I modified and ended up using, thank you Mrig.

Comment: So if I need to copy over some associated information from input sheet between columns C and J to output sheet am I able to insert some extra lines to do this? For example columns D:H to go across with the deduped company names to outputsheet D:H?

Comment: @jrb2b - You can write `outputWS.Range("D" & rowCntr) = inputWS.Range("D" & rowCntr)`

Comment: @jrb2b - For `D:H` range write `outputWS.Range("D" & rowcntr & ":" & "H" & rowcntr).Value = inputWS.Range("D" & rowcntr & ":" & "H" & rowcntr).Value`

Comment: This is great thanks. In the event the number of company names being written into sheet 2 exceeds 2000 can we split into sheet 3 at that point, every 2000 combined companies a new sheet? Thank you.

Comment: @jrb2b - Can be done, but need a new logic to be written altogether.

Comment: Hi Mrig, thank you so much for your help on this yesterday. The code works fine on my test file, but on another file with 50k rows, its throwing up a sub-script out of range error on the array line;            ` outputWS.Range(arr(i - 1) & rowCntr) = inputWS.Range("J" & strRow)`

Comment: I think its due to where there are more than 10 contacts at a single company, the array is only set up to handle 10, can we simply take the first 10 contacts and ditch the rest?

Comment: @jrb2b - Is there any company with more than 10 contacts?

Comment: @jrb2b -After `For i = 1 To count` in the next line write `If i = 11 Then Exit For`